# Find the real ordered pairs $(x,y)$ satisfying $x^2+x=y^4+y^3+y^2+y.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the real ordered pairs $(x,y)$ satisfying $x^2+x=y^4+y^3+y^2+y.$

---

$x^2+x=y^4+y^3+y^2+y$
$4x^2+4x=4y^4+4y^3+4y^2+4y$
$4x^2+4x+1=4y^4+4y^3+4y^2+4y+1$
$(2x+1)^2=4y^4+4y^3+4y^2+4y+1$
I am stuck here.Is there a general method to solve such type of equations?Please help me.

Comment: what kind of pairs do you mean?

Comment: pairs of real numbers?

Comment: yes pair of real numbers.

Comment: you can solve the given equation for $x$ or for $y$

Comment: Is this of any help? $$y^4+y^3+y^2+y=\frac{y^5-y}{y-1}$$(On second thoughts, probably not. The following subtraction is still messy.)

Comment: Are you sure you're not just looking for the integer solutions? There are infinitely many real solutions to this equation, as it describes a curve.

Comment: The answers given are are all integer ordered pairs but question is stated as i have stated.@Théophile

Comment: Then the problem asks for integer solutions. The question must be written wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the assumption that the problem asks for integer solutions, (which is probably the case)

We have $$(2y^2+y)^2<(2x+1)^2=4y^4+4y^3+4y^2+4y+4<(2y^2+y+1)^2$$ for $y > 3$ or $y  <-1$, so we must have $-1 \le y \le 3$. Now bash.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: $$x^2+x=y^4+y^3+y^2+y \Rightarrow \left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2=y^3(y+1)+\left(y+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2$$
$$\Rightarrow \left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2-\left(y+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2=y^3(y+1)$$
$$\Rightarrow (x+y+1)(x-y)=y^3(y+1)$$

Now consider the $4$ cases where $x$ is even or odd and $y$ is even or odd and use divisibility of $2$.

Can you proceed now?

Comment: Integer solutions are always nice, but it's real solutions that are asked for.

Comment: @Arthur Oh sorry, didn't check that. I'm modifying this.